# Optimizing memory managemente for huge variables in Jython

Tags: python, performance, csv, memory, jython

I'm using a roughly 7 to 10 MB CSV file as input, about 65.000 lines which would contain several data fields about corporate hosts: For each one of them, its AssetID, FQDN and six property fields (See below for an example)

```
LServer_0107587|dcsrvivw.gepre.corp|SvcC_0002001|PREPRODUCTION|SvcT_0001086|PREPRODUCTION|SvcB_0000160|INFRASTRUCTURE MANAGEMENT
LServer_0053150|WASCTCEIV-ADM.GADPRE.CORP|SvcC_0002001|PREPRODUCTION|SvcT_0001086|PREPRODUCTION|SvcB_0000160|INFRASTRUCTURE MANAGEMENT
```

Using a `csv.reader` object I iterate over each line and saving its contents to RAM:

```
for prop, column in PROP_COLUMNS:
    prop_value = row[column]
    data[(FQDN, prop)].add(prop_value)
```

Then, when the input file has been completely copied, it's time to dump it to an output file using a different syntax:

```
FQDN, property_name, property_values
```

This works flawlessly for smaller CSV files. This huge CSV, though, seems to clog the JVM allocated memory sometimes depending the current usage of the host in which this is being run. It's the `data.add` bit which I believe is responsible for it.

Mind that the input file is not necessarily sorted by FQDNs, so I can't just go line by line and copying input to output as when a second entry with the same FQDN is found as they should be merged.

I was thinking of mapping this var to a temporary file and using it as the var I'm already using, but I'm not even sure that is possible and/or easy to implement. Using a database is not possible for now I'm afraid

I'm not yet acquainted with everything that Python has to offer me, so the ideal solution might as well be right in front of me and I'm not able to see it... I hope someone versed with it can help a fellow developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't store the full dataset in memory, you could look at using the disk as (temporary) storage. E.g. Every FQDN could be saved to a file.

Something like (this is half-pseudocode!):

```
temp_dir = tempfile.mktmpdir()
for row in csv:
    # Get FQDN and properties here
    fqdn_filepath = os.path.join(temp_dir, FQDN.name)
    if not os.path.exists(fqdn_filepath):
        # Create it from scratch
    else:
        # Add the new properties to the existing FQDN file

# Now you have finished iterating the CSV, you have a bunch of FQDN files
# Now process them one by one
with open_output_file() as output:
    for fqdn_file in sorted(os.path.files_in_dir(temp_dir)):
        output.write_fqdn_data()

delete temp_dir
```